Weird character showing up during automation of GitHub PR changelog
I'm using a workflow to automate the creation of a changelog when a PR is open.
Basically, I'm fetching all the commits in a PR and updating the PR body to look something like this:
Changelog:
- feat: new file
- feat: update to file

However, along the way something weird is happening and this is what I see in the output:

Not sure where this arrow is coming from.
For clarity, this is what the code looks like:
          const commitMessages = `\${{ steps.fetch-commits.outputs.commit_messages }}`;
          let changelog = "## Changelog:\n";
          
          commitMessages.split('|').forEach(line => {
            changelog += `${line}`;
          });
          
          const prNumber = context.payload.pull_request.number;
          const owner = context.repo.owner;
          const repo = context.repo.repo;
          
          await github.rest.pulls.update({
            owner: owner,
            repo: repo,
            pull_number: prNumber,
            body: changelog,
            headers: {
              authorization: `token ${process.env.PAT}`
            }
          });


Strange. Try this: let changelog = \## Changelog:\n${commitMessages.split('|').map(line => `- ${line.trim()}`).join('\n')}`;`

@mplungjan - now the arrow does not show up, but the initial "f" is removed. Instead of "feature(SCA-0000): Create test.txt" it shows "eature(SCA-0000): Create test.txt"

Interesting. Sounds like you have a corrupted message or some non-ascii chars

@mplungjan seems so, will try a different approach and see how it goes. If you post an answer I'll mark it as an answer. Appreciate the help!

Is the backslash at the start of commit messages needed?

@James - I tried to remove it, but the same still happens. As mplungjan said, it seems to be some weird chars coming from the message.

I just ended up changing this part of the code to use bash and the issue disappeared. A mistery indeed.
